# Geeting null when i use BindView in Butterknife

Tags: android, butterknife

Here my topActivity which extend BaseActivity

activity_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"> 
  <View android:id="@+id/activity_top_group_area1" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

TopActivity.java

```
public class TopActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.activity_top_group_area1)

    View mViewClickArea1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        # do something... but mViewClickArea1 is null here.
     }
    }
```

And the BaseActivity Which extend AppCompactActivity in which i do some centralize permission work

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompactActivity  {

# do some Run time Permission work that is ...
private int requestCodeM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    boolean isPermissionGranted = false;
    if (requestCodeM == requestCode) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            /*--------------------------------------------------*/
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
               if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                   isPermissionGranted=true;
               }else {
                   isPermissionGranted=false;
                   break;
               }
            }
            permissiongrantedResult(requestCode,isPermissionGranted);
        }
    }
}

public void addRequestPermission(String[] permissionRequest, int requestCode) {
    this.requestCodeM = requestCode;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityWithRequestPermission.this, permissionRequest, requestCode);
}

public abstract void permissiongrantedResult(int requestCode, boolean grantStatus);`enter code here`
}
```

Kindly look at this.

Comment: post your `activity_top.xml`

Comment: Post logcat so every one can easily identified where actual error coming.

Comment: hi @akhilesh0707 here is my top activity xm                                           l<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<View
    android:id="@+id/activity_top_group_area1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Check the name of your layout: is it "top_activity" or "activity_top"?

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your code .

**Change xml code to this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/activity_top_group_area1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Check `project gradle`**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    // add this in your code
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'  
}
```

**Check `app gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'  // add this 

...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    // add this 
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0
}
```

Comment: if using latest version switch to annotationProcessor as in section Download @ http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: You change to the confirmed version number and try it in my own way@Raghunandan

Comment: thanks @KeLiuyue  ...actually i forgot to add the dependency    'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0' After placing this dependency its work fine

Comment: @AbidKhan Good luck to you .